# regex of backslash in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the regex of a backslash, if the backslash is not present in the `test` string and not in the regex expression it is working, I tried `\\` and `\\\\`

This is my code:

```
def getString():
    test=',"string":"x\u002fg06HaX0M\u002fuTJh7Q",Bla'
    m=re.match(r",\"string\":\"([\w\d\\\\]+)\",",test)
    print(m.group(1))
```

The error i get is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like unicode chars present in your input string (*\u002f*). There isn't an actual backslash character present in the input. And also I think you want to get the characters present inside the double quotes which exists next to `"string":`. So use a negated character class like `[^"]+` to match any character (including unicodes) but not of double quotes, zero or more times.

```
>>> st=',"string":"x\u002fg06HaX0M\u002fuTJh7Q",Bla'
>>> re.match(u',"string":"([^"]+)",',st).group(1)
'x/g06HaX0M/uTJh7Q'
>>> re.match(r',"string":"([^"]+)",',st).group(1)
'x/g06HaX0M/uTJh7Q'
```

Comment: Why there isn't actual backslash?

Comment: `\u002f` is a Unicode representation of a single character.

Comment: `p=''
    for line in text.splitlines():
        if 'string' in line:
            for part in line.split(','):
                if 'string' in part:
                    p=part
    m=re.match(u'.*"string":"([^"]+)"',p).group(1)` Any idea why this code doesn't decode the unicode characters? print(m) gives string with `\u002f`